# Parse PHP Session Data From File with Node.js

Tags: regex

I will share PHP session data to Node.js by read the file directly. The content of sesion file is like this:

```
user_id|i:2;password|s:10:"asdfg;hjkl";username|s:16:"kamshory;mas"roy";
```

I already use `php-unserialize` but failed. I alse split the sting using regular expression `/;(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g` and `/(".*?"|[^";\s]+)(?=\s*;|\s*$)/g` but still failed.

How can I split the string become

```
user_id|i:2
password|s:10:"asdfg;hjkl"
username|s:16:"kamshory;mas"roy"
```

using Node.js

Thank you

Comment: Please, next time add more fine-grained tags, so that it's PHP related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, one option could be to capture in a group `()` what you want to keep and match the following `;`

```
([^|\r\n]+\|[a-z]:\d+(?::"[^"\r\n]*(?:"(?!;)[^"\r\n]*)*")?);
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^|\r\n]+` Match any char except `|` or a newline
  - `\|[a-z]:\d+` Match `|`, char a-z, `:` and 1+ digits
  - `(?:` Non caputure group

    - `:"` Match literally
    - `[^"\r\n]*` Match any char except `"` or newline
    - `(?:` Non capture group

      - `"(?!;)[^"\r\n]*` Match `"` if not directly followed by `;`, then 0+ times not `"`
    - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times (In case there are no `"` in between)
    - `"` Match literally
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `);` Close group 1 and match following `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xNqMdf/1)

In the replacement use the first capturing group

```
$1\n
```

```js
const regex = /([^|\r\n]+\|[a-z]:\d+(?::"[^"\r\n]*(?:"(?!;)[^"\r\n]*)*")?);/g;
const str = `user_id|i:2;password|s:10:"asdfg;hjkl";username|s:16:"kamshory;mas"roy";`;
const subst = `$1\n`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

---

Another option could be using the strings `user_id`, `password` and `username` with matching the `i` or `s`

```
(user_id\|i:\d+|(?:password|username)\|s:\d+:".*?");
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJOFPx/1)

```js
const regex = /(user_id\|i:\d+|(?:password|username)\|s:\d+:".*?");/g;
const str = `user_id|i:2;password|s:10:"asdfg;hjkl";username|s:16:"kamshory;mas"roy";`;
const subst = `$1\n`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```